# What python virtual environment install locally and system-wise?

Tags: python-venv

When Python virtual environment `venv` is activated, I wonder what installation will be added to the local `venv` and what go to the OS as system-wise?

I ask after notice that my LAMP installation, while `venv` is activated, has the system-wise effect i.e. NOT within the environment as I thought.

Comment: all the pip installs are locally, I guess thats the purpose of virtual environment. sudo pip - globally

Comment: that sounds right...

Comment: @dnit13 Please put your comment into an answer to get accepted. Thank  you.